# FFTW3 in ubuntu: error in linking

Tags: environment-variables

I have installed FFTW3 in the newest version of ubuntu (downloaded yesterday). when I compile the cpp file I get the error:

```
fatal error: fftw3.h: No such file or directory.
```

I used cmd line:

```
g++ *.cpp -lfftw -lfftw_threads -ls -fopenmp -o test.out
```

fftw is installed in `/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4` and I
located the header file `/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/api/fftw3.h`

Is there something to do with env variables? I am very new to ubuntu and linux, any help will much appreciated.

Please dont close this as a offtopic, I have googled this issue a lot and couldnt find a solution...

Comment: How exactly did you install fftw? Did you install the development components or just runtime libraries? If you have installed to a non-standard location, you will need to set g++ include and library paths appropriately. Why did you not install the normal binary package (`libfftw3-dev`) from the repositories?

Comment: Add `-I/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/api/` and `-L/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/lib` to the compilation line. The -L path might need adjustment depending on where the libraries are.

Comment: @Harris: Thank you, it helped to get rid off the error...Do you have any suggestions to automate this, instead of typing it in the compilation line?

Comment: @steeldriver: I wasnt aware of that method.. I downloaded the latest file from FFTW.org and installed with --enable_threads FLAG...The installation was fine...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a quick solution, add to the compilation line:

```
-I/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/api/ -L/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/lib
```

The -L path might need adjustment depending on where the libraries are.

To automate this you can add the following to your `.bashrc` file:

```
export LDFLAGS="-L/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/lib" 
export CFLAGS="-I/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/api"
export CPPFLAGS="-I/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/api"
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/home/student/Downloads/fftw-3.3.4/lib
```

Comment: Thank you..this helps...Also I figured out from @steeldriver' s question that I havent installed the FFTW correctly. I didnt login as root to install and couldnt figure out whether it installed correctly or not..Now I reinstalled fftw and problem solved...thank you all for the suggestions...